# Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Invalid number of arguments for function isnull. Expected: 1; Found: 2; Error On Databricks

Tags: databricks

The following SQL code executes without any issues on SQL 2019, but when run the code on Databricks I get the error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Invalid number of arguments for function isnull. Expected: 1; Found: 2;

;WITH CTE1 AS
 (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts_primarysecondaryfocus)RowNum FROM dataverse.account_hv
 ),CTE2 AS
 (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts_primarysecondaryfocus)RowNum FROM dataverse.OptionsetMetadata_hv
 )
 SELECT C1.Id,C1.SinkCreatedOn,C1.SinkModifiedOn,C1.statecode,C1.statuscode
       ,CASE WHEN C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus<>ISNULL(C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus,'')THEN C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus ELSE C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus END AS ts_primarysecondaryfocus
       ,C1.customertypecode,C1.address1_addresstypecode,C1.accountclassificationcode,C1.ts_easeofworking 
       ,CASE WHEN C1.ts_ukrow<>ISNULL(C2.ts_ukrow,'')THEN C2.ts_ukrow ELSE C1.ts_ukrow END AS ts_ukrow 
       ,C1.preferredappointmenttimecode,C1.xpd_relationshipstatus,C1.ts_relationship
 FROM CTE1 C1 LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.RowNum = C2.RowNum
```

Any thoughts on why I don't incur any issues with ISNULL on SQL 2019 but I get the error on Databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/coalesce) function in Spark behaves like you are expecting. Use it instead of [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/isnull) (which takes a single argument and returns whether the parameter is null).